# Can't deserialize data in the Kafka Stream using Spring Cloud Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-cloud

I am creating a simple Kafka Streaming application. My Producer is producing protobuf serialize messages to one topic and I'm using that topic in Kafka Streaming application to consumer messages. I'm trying to deserialize messages using `valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerde` in my application.yml file. I'm getting below errors.

***Errors:***

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 10, 13, 84, 105, 109, 101, 114, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 16, 1, 34, 12, 8, -126, -107, -127, -120, 6, 16, -12, -88, -117, -114, 2]] from topic [MYINPUT-TOPIC]
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x1ff0a0d (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.reportInvalid(UTF32Reader.java:195) ~[jackson-core-2.11.3.jar:2.11.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.read(UTF32Reader.java:158) ~[jackson-core-2.11.3.jar:2.11.3]
```

My `application.yml` configuration file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: process
    stream:
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 3
            valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerde
            back-off-initial-interval: 100
            retryable-exceptions:
              javax:
                validation:
                  ValidationException: false
          destination: MYINPUT-TOPIC
          group: consumer-group
          concurrency: 2
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: localhost:9092
            schema-registry-u-r-l: http://localhost:8081
            auto-offset-reset: "earliest"
            configuration:
              commit-interval-ms: 100
```

process method to print actual deserialize message in the log:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ProcessStream {

//Here below Timer object is Protobuf's auto-generated class, I am using it to deserialize messages. 
//I'm getting byte Aarry on this method when I'm debugging it.  
    @Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<String, Timer>> process() {
        return (InputStream) -> {
            InputStream.foreach((k,v) -> log.info(String.format("key: %s, value: %s",k, v)));
        };
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. How can I deserialize messages using protobuf in Kafka Stream?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a protobuf Serde that wraps a proper protobuf deserializer. Confluent schema registry provides a protobuf Serde implementation. See [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/protobuf-serde/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/streams/serdes/protobuf/KafkaProtobufSerde.java) for details. I haven't tested with this particular implementation, but looks like that should work. If you are using this (or a custom protobuf serde implementation), then you can register it in your Spring Cloud Stream application by simply providing a bean of that type. See below.

```
@Bean
public KafkaProtobufSerde<Timer> kafkaProtobufSerde() {
}
```

Kafka Streams binder in Spring Cloud Stream will detect this bean and match against your consumer type.

**Update based on the sample application shared in the comments below**

I am able to run your sample application after making the following changes in your configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: process
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          group: consumer-group
          concurrency: 1
          headerMode: none
          destination: MESSAGING-TIMER-EXAMPLE
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
```

You needed the `kafka.streams.binder` prefix. After making the change, I am able to start the application without any errors. I see these in the startup logs.

```
2021-07-29 15:10:42.995  INFO 65137 --- [           main] .c.s.b.k.s.KafkaStreamsFunctionProcessor : Key Serde used for process-in-0: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
2021-07-29 15:10:42.996  INFO 65137 --- [           main] .c.s.b.k.s.KafkaStreamsFunctionProcessor : Value Serde used for process-in-0: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerde
...
...
2021-07-29 15:10:43.629  INFO 65137 --- [           main] c.j.ListenerMessagingStreamsApplication  : Started ListenerMessagingStreamsApplication in 1.836 seconds (JVM running for 2.305)
```

I noticed that you named your yaml configuration file as `application-LOCAL.yml`. If that is what you are using, then make sure that you set this property at runtime `--spring.config.name=application-LOCAL`. Otherwise, rename that file to `application.yml`.

Comment: Hi, I updated the below code with the bean that you have suggested but it's still not working. getting this error:  ```org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaStreamsFunctionProcessorInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.```

Comment: If you can provide a small sample application on GitHub where we can reproduce the issue, that would be helpful in triaging the issue further.

Comment: ```private String schemaRegistryUrl = "http://localhost:8081";
    @Bean
    public KafkaProtobufSerde<Timer> newTimerSerde() {
        final KafkaProtobufSerde<Timer> serde = new KafkaProtobufSerde<>(Timer.class);
        final Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,this.schemaRegistryUrl);
        serde.configure(config, false);
        return serde;
    }```

Comment: Please find the sample project: https://github.com/vishaldhanani/listener_messaging_streams     Please check it and let me know where exactly the issue is! Thank you for your support. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, please see my updates in the answer above.

Comment: Hi @sobychacko, I have changed the settings as you suggested, I am getting errors while my process function takes **Timer** protobuf object as input. see here:  `public Consumer<KStream<String, Timer>> process() {` ----> I'm getting this error: Can't deserialize data [[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 10, 13, 84, 105, 109, 101, 114, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 16, 1, 34, 11, 8, -107, -49, -122, -120, 6, 16, -52, -74, -44, 3]] from topic [MESSAGING-TIMER-EXAMPLE]

Comment: Can you share your source code? So, I can try to run it in my system.